# TLS connection to MongoDB in Quarkus

Tags: mongodb, quarkus

I am attempting to connect from Quarkus to a MongoDB instance in the cloud which requires TLS. I have the certificate file for the server but cannot see how to use it with Quarkus.

I currently have the following properties set

```
quarkus.mongodb.connection-string = mongodb://blah:blah@mydomain.com:27017
quarkus.mongodb.database=school
quarkus.mongodb.tls=true
```

There does not appear to be anywhere to set the certificate file.

I cannot get past this error

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Warren

Comment: I've never used Quarkus.  Does it accept connection string options like [tlsCAFile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#urioption.tlsCAFile)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific TLS settings for MongoDB with Quarkus.
If your certificate has a known root (which didn't seem to be the case), there is nothing more to do.
If your certificate is not knownw by your JVM, you need to use the `keetool` of your JVM to import it.

Be careful that if you deploy your application as a native executable, there is some steps to follow:  https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl